# PHP command shell_exec() not working for my custom Java app5

Tags: java, php

I have made a custom java program to output a license and am trying to run it in php.

```
$deviceid="12345";
$command_app = 'java -jar /home/myname/secure/mycommand.jar ';
$privateKey = 'QEFAASCAmEwggJdAgE';
$command_app_args = "\"$privateKey\" deviceid=$deviceid";
$command=$command_app.$command_app_args;
$license = shell_exec($command);
```

The problem is that $license is empty every time, I tried to print out the $command using

```
echo $command;
```

and then ran that command directly in the linux terminal and the xml output was correct.

I am using

```
System.out.println()
```

in the java app to print all the xml output.  I tried something simple like

```
shell_exec('ls -l') ;
```

and sure enough if worked.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get for `which java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct is that the command java is not in PHP's shell path.  Try something like this:

```
$command_app = '`which java` -jar /home/myname/secure/mycommand.jar ';
```

The command `which java` will return the full path to the java executable...

Comment: $java = `which java`; echo $java; produced nothing, however $java = `ls -l`; echo $java; worked

Comment: `which ls` produced /bin/ls so for some reason php can't locate java even with the which command

Comment: I used the full path /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java in the php command instead of java and it worked.