# Apache not aware of window path variables?

Tags: java, php, apache, command-line

I am trying to do the same as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260277/php-exec-java-on-windows-produces-no-output). I want to be able to get a result when I do this:

```
$javaExec = shell_exec('java -version 2>&1');
var_dump($javaExec);
```

However, all I get is:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I run "java -version" from the command line (i.e. cmd), I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

But I can't get PHP/Apache to get the same result. Is there something I need to do to make Apache aware of the path environment variables?

I tried restarting Apache and my PC, but unfortunately no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: _Small Aside:_ You could do with updating your version of java mine says `1.8.0_101`

Comment: Does that mean that to run java -version, you need to explicitly specify the path? Because I can't help but think there must be a way to make Apache "aware" of the location of Java.

Comment: This is _probably_ a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007181/php-command-shell-exec-not-working-for-my-custom-java-app5 or maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154715/running-java-jar-from-php-exec-or-shell-exec-isnt-working-for-batik

Comment: It's not an apache thing, is a user variables in Operative system thing. Different users/different path variables. Apache HTTPD has a file called envvars where you can store all the system variables you want it to start with. If you start apache with apachectl script or anything that loads that file first, you will get what you are looking for.